# i want to create a dynamic "INDEX" with a two dimensional range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want to create a dynamic INDEX with a two dimensional range, so when i add new products. it would automatically be added into the INDEX function within "Microsoft EXCEL"

-

i've already found a source, but i can't get it too work. only when i separate the code it actually does something but when i try it on my index. i get error codes. (https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index)

-

i did need too translate my code and i do not have all code anymore because i deleted and did retry. i'm sorry for that.

-

=INDEX($A$2:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNTA($A:$A),COUNTA($1:$1),MATCH(BLAD1!$A$4,$A:$A),0),MATCH(BLAD!$A$5,$1:$1),0)))

-

#######    #NAAM?    #N/B?

Comment: No need for dynamic: `=INDEX($1:$1048576,MATCH(BLAD1!$A$4,$A:$A,0),MATCH(BLAD!$A$5,$1:$1,0))`

Comment: ah, thanks tho :P

i did use google first too find the function in dutch my excel exam on school will be dutch so this one will help me alot!

Hope there is someone who knows how to make this index function dynamic. my teacher said it wasn't possible because the index function uses hard code.

Comment: @ScottCraner this is just what i typed i want to work with a sheet where lots and lots of data will be pasted in and best would be if it was dynamic so i don't have too make it work each time again. But thanks for help tho! ;)

Comment: It is possible but not needed.  You already refer to the whole sheet to do the dynamic sizing.  there is no need for the extra steps, it will only run slower in this case.

Comment: The only time one should create a dynamic size array is when using array type formula which INDEX is not.

Comment: hmm, so i realy do have too change the code again each time i have new data? :/

Comment: No, the formula above will look at the whole sheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner oh, thanks i'm gonna try it out :P

Comment: Nope still not working 
=INDEX(PLAYERS!$1:$1048576;VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!B3;PLAYERS!$A:$A);VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!F1;PLAYERS!$1:$1);0) #N/B i get when i enter this

Comment: you did not match mine: `=INDEX(PLAYERS!$1:$1048576;VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!B3;PLAYERS!$A:$A;0);VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!F1;PLAYERS!$1:$1;0))`

Comment: ah, i see i forgot too state if i wanted the exact result are not. i'm sorry..

and thankyou realy much man!

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Craner << shoutout to this man!

this worked for me.

DUTCH
=INDEX(PLAYERS!$1:$1048576;VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!B3;PLAYERS!$A:$A;0);VERGELIJKEN(Blad1!F1;PLAYERS!$1:$1;0))

ENGLISH
=INDEX(PLAYERS!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Blad1!B3,PLAYERS!$A:$A,0),MATCH(Blad1!F1,PLAYERS!$1:$1,0))